# How HTML content changes dynamically upon animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please, have a look at the following page: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_39361/index.html#!/page_about. There is an animation I cannot tell how it is created. The moving part of the page is represented by li's in the following code:

```
<ul>
 <li id="page_about" style="display: block; left: 0px;">
 <li id="page_services" style="display: none; left: -1260.5px;">
 <li id="page_portfolio" style="display: none; left: -1260.5px;">
 <li id="page_contacts" style="display: none; left: -1260.5px;">
 <li id="page_privacy" style="display: none; left: -1260.5px;">
 <li id="page_more" style="display: none; left: -1260.5px;">
</ul>
```

The most strange to me is the above numbers and the values of display are being changed dynamically inside HTML(!!) every time the top links of the page are clicked. How? Sorry, I have no idea about that. I 'd appreciate some help on how to realize such an animation. Is there any Jquery or a script responsible for that?
Thank you very much

Comment: `elem.style.left`... It's basic JavaScript.

Comment: Just a reminder: JQuery is not a language. It's a library written in a language. That language is javascript.

Comment: And your question is??? ... do you want that exact animation??? yo haven't tried anything. Just want to copy?

Answer (score 2):

The animation is being performed by a few JS sources included in the html. The motion is performed by the jQuery easing script. For example, to go back to a previous section, your code says:

```
.animate({left:-getOutsideLeft()}, 350,'easeInSine', function(){
                     $(this).css({display:'none'});
```

You can learn about all the easing functions offered by jQuery [here](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html).

It's not strange that the numbers inside the HTML change dynamically. The Javascript and it's functions for the easing control those numbers.